# Macbook won't turn on

Tags: macbook-pro, unibody

I have a 2008 aluminium unibody Macbook and after being off for about a month won't turn on. It is full charged (it has a battery indicator on the side). I've tried an SMC reset and the like but am really very stumped. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: what does it do, anything ? nothing! anything on the screen ? where was it stored? what does it do with power cable plugged in ?,

Comment: The screen does nothing, pushing the power button does nothing. When I plug a charger in the light on the charger turns red as it charges and the battery indicator in the side shows it charging, other than that...nothing. It was just sitting on my desk.

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not specify what  have you tried this is going to be a guess game:

1***Take the battery out and put it back in.

That usually solves the problem of "oxidized" connectors.

You can try to clean the connectors but normally just in and out does it.

2*** try the power button, by pressing in rapid sequence or holding it for 10 seconds.

*Since you just disclosed that when plugged in the battery shows to be charging, and before you said it is fully charged, so give it time and see if the charging light goes off.*

Comment: Thanks, sadly I've tried that the battery connections are fine.